# Ruby on Rails active record syntax to query status updates in a twitter style application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a twitter style application whereby a user follows many people.
This is achieved using a self-referential association.

This all works very nice but my brain has just gone dead while trying to figure out the active record syntax needed to list status updates (posts) from people the user follows ordered by time in a single query.

My user model looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end
```

And the post model is

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

For completeness the Friendship model

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
 end
```

Ultimately what I want to do is

@user.friends.reviews.all

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that a friend is also a User object, so that Friend also has_many :posts:

`@user.friends.posts.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC"`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. friend is a User object and has_many :posts but when I try to use your snippet I get

undefined method `posts' for #<Class:0x102efd118>

Comment: You also need User has_many :friends above your :through line.

Comment: Not sure I understand you there.

Are you saying I need to have 


has_many :friends defined twice in the user model?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is stemming from the fact that `@user.friends` is returning an array and so `.posts` doesn't exist on an array (even if it's an array of AR objects).

I would probably define something like `User#friend_posts` which builds up an array of friends posts that you can return.

Something like:

```
def friend_posts
  posts = []
  friends.each { |friend| posts << friend.posts }
  posts
end
```

Comment: The problem I see with that is that the posts are not sorted by the create time. Also, this would involve grabbing every single post from each person the user follows. It just feels like there should be a nicer way of doing this.